# insert xlookup among mulitple workbooks with multiple sheets wrapped in if/then statements

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel-formula, xlookup

Need a review of the logic.
2 workbooks (for now) with 5 worksheets each.
flag school's master with cases found under the RC HH export  by team
insert Columns for keepers with hearders to mitigate the filtered data and exact match
concatenate establised for searcing on the source file
need to perform match on dst file to src file and populate dst file with CMR filed form src file IF present
do not overwrite any existing data in CMR column on dst file
only address used rows on respective sheets for data conservation
src and dst files are homed to sharepoint   per microsoft  cannot direct open to those files thru vba
need to ensure the respective files are open on the user's desktop for this to run and no other users loogged in while executing
office 365 environment

```
Sub Trial()  
    Dim src As String
    Dim dst As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim ALERT As String
    Dim Concatenate As String
    Dim FILLDATA As String
    Dim SOURCE As String
    Dim Head1 As String
    Dim Head2 As String
    Dim Check As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim N As Long

    
    src = "RC_SCH_SORTED_TODAY.xlsx"
    dst = "Copy Fall 2021_Schools_master list_8.24.21.xlsx"
    ALERT = "ALERT-RC-Match"
    Concatenate = "=RC[-47]&""-""&RC[-46]&""-""&RC[-45]"
    Head1 = "FLAG FOR PULL FROM RC EXPORT"
    Head2 = "Concatenated Search"
    FILLDATAMS = "=XLOOKUP(@AX:AX,wbSource[[#RC SPARKS],[Concatenated Search]],wbDest[[#SPARKS],[CMR'#]],,0) "
    FILLDATADC = "=XLOOKUP(@AX:AX,wbSource[[#RC DC],[Concatenated Search]],wbDest[[#DC],[CMR'#]],,0) "
    FILLDATADR = "=XLOOKUP(@AX:AX,wbSource[[#RC Danielle],[Concatenated Search]],wbDest[[#Danielle],[CMR'#]],,0) "
    FILLDATANC = "=XLOOKUP(@AX:AX,wbSource[[#RC Natalie],[Concatenated Search]],wbDest[[#Natalie],[CMR'#]],,0) "
    FILLDATAGH = "=XLOOKUP(@AX:AX,wbSource[[#RC Gabe],[Concatenated Search]],wbDest[[#Gabe],[CMR'#]],,0) "
    Set wbSource = Workbooks(src)
    Set wbDest = Workbooks(dst)
    
    Workbooks(src).Activate
    Workbooks(dst).Activate

'   sparks's team workload
     Sheets("SPARKS").Select
     Range("AW1").Value = Head1
     Range("AX1").Value = Head2
    
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     lastrow = Worksheets("SPARKS").UsedRange.Rows.Count
     N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(x1Up).Row
     Range("AX2:AX" & N).Formula2R1C1 = Concatenate
     For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1


        If Worksheets("SPARKS").Range("AF" & r).Value = "" Then
            Worksheets("SPARKS").Cells("AF").Value = FILLDATAMS & Worksheets("SPARKS").Cells("AW") = ALERT
        Else
        End If
     Next r
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

the break is in the logic within the if/then
this is repeated among the other worksheets for their respective sources and i am stuck on the logic.  I am not formally trained but have been tasked with working this out.  I have multiple other workbooks to perform similar functions among for data consolidation to the support teams.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? The entire first paragraph is pretty much one sentence...

Comment: I ran out of breath trying to read the whole sentence. Please edit your question and clarify what is your exact issue. If possible, please provide a screenshot of your data and what are you expecting the code to do.

Comment: @RaymondWu. Sorry i am longwinded.   I am comparing records within different workbooks that contain similar data for multiple teams.  on the Destination file  SOME records will already have the "CMR" field populated.    I am wanting to insert the xlookup "FILLDATAxx" nto that column and on the dest file ONLY for those who are not manually populated AND place an"ALERT" in column AW for the record insertion as the result of the inserted formula is identical to the pre-existing data.  it needs a visual trigger for the end users

Comment: @BruceWayne.   when i debug the code, it breaks at the If/Then statemtn  and frequently will break at the "N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(x1Up).Row"     obvioulsy not yet in production

Comment: @Jonathan What error did you get? (error code, description and which line)

Comment: I have not use Xlookup before but I believe your formula is wrong since you are concatenating the variable name in the string itself.

Comment: @Jonathan to be clear, it should be `xlUp` (x lowercase-L up) not `x1Up` ("x one up") is that a typo here on SO, or also your code?

Comment: @BruceWayne  thank you  for the xlUp  syntax  that rectifies the runtime 1004 in line 589 with the N = Cells.....

Comment: after fixing line 58   i now get runtime 5 invalid procedure  call or argument on line 62  which is  the "THEN" of the if /then nesting  statemtint

I have defined a term  Dim Concatenate As String  and defined that term as a formula  that i have appended above.   

  Worksheets("SPARKS").Cells("AF").Value = FILLDATAMS & Worksheets("SPARKS").Cells("AW") = ALERT